# Writing Unix line breaks on Windows with JRuby

Tags: ruby, windows, unix, jruby, newline

I'm writing a Ruby script to generates a Unix shell script, but I'm unable to get JRuby to write Unix line breaks on Windows.

I have written a file `test.rb` which contains:

```
File.open("test.sh", 'w') do |f|
  f.write("#!/bin/sh\n")
  f.write("echo hello\n")
end
```

When I execute it with the command `java -jar jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar test.rb` then the generated file contains `\r\n` line breaks instead of `\n` line breaks.

How can I force JRuby to write a text file with Unix newlines?

Comment: tried the magic comment `# encoding: utf-8-unix` at the top of the file?

Comment: `# encoding: utf-8-unix` did not help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding "b" to the parameters of `File.open`

```
File.open("test.sh", 'wb') do |f|
  f.write("#!/bin/sh\n")
  f.write("echo hello\n")
end
```

The documentation for the [IO class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) says about it the following:

```
Mode |  Meaning
-----+--------------------------------------------------------
 "b" |  Binary file mode (may appear with
     |  any of the key letters listed above).
     |  Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows. And
     |  sets external encoding to ASCII-8BIT unless explicitly
     |  specified.
-----+--------------------------------------------------------
```